# Images in the Admin But All are Selected as "No Image"

Tags: product-images

We are coming across a weird issue with one of our websites. We have all of the images uploaded into the admin and we see them when we are in manage products, on the images tab. BUT all of the images are selected as "No Image" instead of "Base Image" "Thumbnail" "Small Image". How can I fix this? Can I do this in an import? If so could you please show an example import sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Export**
System >Import/Export > Dataflow Profiles > Export All Products
Set Export Filters and Run Profile > Run Profile in Popup.
File can be located via ftp in var/export

Edit csv - need to find and copy **_media_image** for each product to all the following columns **image,** **small_image**  and **thumbnail**

May need a bit of csv "magic" as the exported file may drop the _media_image data to separate rows. To make the csv easier to edit you can delete all columns apart from
store, websites, type, category_ids, sku, image, small_image, thumbnail & _media_image_image and the re-import should work OK.

**Re-import**
System >Import/Export > Dataflow Profiles > Import All Products
Upload File
Save & Continue Edit
Run Profile > Select File > Run Profile in Popup